# Commission calculation

Tags: c#, linq, hash-map

I am trying to improve the performance of the current solution for calculating commission in a betting platform.

The following is the code currently used to solve the problem. The primary problem here is the `CalculateCommission` method, which is ugly and seems to do the same thing multiple times. I've tried but not been able to come up with a way to simplify the query (or solve the problem in some other way not thought of), so am looking for community help to fix the problem.

```
//All agents commissions for the current user
userCommissions = List<Commission>

public class Commission
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long AgentId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public long? SportId { get; set; }
    public long? LeagueId { get; set; }
    public EMarketType MarketType { get; set; }
    public int Commission { get; set; }
}

public class AgentCommission
{
    public long AgentId { get; set; }
    public int Commission{ get; set; }

    public AgentCommission()
    {
    }

    public AgentCommission(long agentId, int commission)
    {
        Commission= commission;
        AgentId = agentId;
    }
}

public class BetCommission
{
    public int TotalCommission { get; private set; }
    public List<AgentCommission> AgentCommissions { get; }

    public BetCommission()
    {
        AgentCommissions = new List<AgentCommission>();
    }

    public void AddAgentCommission(AgentCommission agentCommission)
    {
        AgentCommissions.Add(agentCommission);
        TotalCommission += agentCommission.Commission;
    }
}

protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, BetCommission> betCommissionsByUser;

public void CalculateCommission() {
    var levelCommissions = userCommissions.GroupBy(x => new { x.MarketType, x.Level }).ToList();
    var keysGrouping = userCommissions.GroupBy(x => new { x.SportId, x.LeagueId, x.MarketType }).ToList();

    foreach (var bpKey in keysGrouping)
    {
        var betCommission = new BetCommission();
        var sportId = bpKey.Key.SportId ?? 0;
        var leagueId = bpKey.Key.LeagueId ?? 0;

        var key = $"{userId}-{sportId}-{leagueId}-{bpKey.Key.MarketType}";

        var commissionsForCurrentKey = levelCommissions.Where(x => x.Key.MarketType == bpKey.Key.MarketType)
                                                     .SelectMany(x => x)
                                                     .Where(x => (x.SportId == null || x.SportId == sportId) && (x.LeagueId == null || x.LeagueId == leagueId))
                                                     .OrderBy(x => x.Level).ThenByDescending(x => x.LeagueId).ThenByDescending(x => x.SportId);

        var currentLevel = 0;
        foreach (var pos in commissionsForCurrentKey)
        {
            if (currentLevel == pos.Level)
                continue;

            currentLevel = pos.Level;
            betCommission.AddAgentCommission(new AgentCommission(pos.AgentId, pos.Commission));
        }

        betCommissionsByUser.AddOrUpdate(key, betCommission, (k, v) => betCommission);
    }
}
```

Some background information on the problem:

The platform has a hierarchy of agents that can get commission from users lower in the hierarchy. Commissions are configured to be either global or tied to a specific sport or league. In addition to the optional Sport and League, a commission also has a required value `MarketType`.

When calculating the commission for an agent, the most specific commission configured for the agent is what should be used. For instance, if an agent has configured both a global commission and a sport-specific commission, then the sport-tied one takes precedence.

The goal is to have a dictionary where I can obtain the positions (for all agents in the hierarchy) with a single lookup.

An example of the commission structure:

Commission table on User 1:

> ```
>             General       Soccer      Champions League
> Agent 1       1%                      10%
> Agent 2       1%          5%          10%
> Agent 3       0%          0%          10%
> Agent 4       0%          5%
> ```

If User 1 places a bet on a Soccer match in the France League 1, the commission should be as follows:

> ```
> Agent 1 = 1%
> Agent 2 = 5%
> Agent 3 = 0%
> Agent 4 = 5%
> ```

But if User 1 places a bet on a Soccer match in Champions League, the commission should be as follows:

> ```
> Agent 1 = 10%
> Agent 2 = 10%
> Agent 3 = 10%
> Agent 4 = 5%
> ```

Comment: @Heslacher Yes userCommissions = List<Commission>. I have also edited the post

Comment: @Heslacher Sorry, a type error, have changed it and also included the AgentCommission and BetCommission class

Comment: Could you add some code showing the usage?

Comment: Where's the input? How does `CalculateCommission` know where the user placed his bet?

Comment: The code doesn't compile. The `Commission` class have a property with the same name, which is not legal.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to change would be the query for `commissionForCurrentKey` to include the condition `x.Level != 0` if `Level` can be negative too, or `x.Level > 0` if it can't be negative (which I assume now).
In this way any item having a `Level == 0` would be eleminated, hence at least the first iteration in the `foreach (var pos in commissionsForCurrentKey)` loop wouldn't be senseless.

I would like to encourage you to always use braces `{}` for single statement `if`'s to make the code less error prone.

By extracting the creation of the `AgentCommission`'s to a separate method your code will benefit regarding readability and maintainability.

This could look like so

```
private IEnumerable<AgentCommission> CreateAgentCommissions(IOrderedEnumerable<Commission> commissionsForCurrentKey)
{
    int currentLevel = 0;
    foreach (var pos in commissionsForCurrentKey)
    {
        if (currentLevel == pos.Level) { continue; }

        currentLevel = pos.Level;
        yield return new AgentCommission(pos.AgentId, pos.Commission);
    }
}
```

Variables should be placed as near as their usage, so `key` could be just placed above the call to `AddOrUpdate()`.

By changing this second `.Where()` to just compare like `(x.SportId == bpKey.Key.SportId) && (x.LeagueId == bpKey.Key.LeagueId)` it is more readable too.

Instead of writing

```
.OrderBy().ThenByDescending().ThenByDescending()
```

it would be more readable to write

```
.OrderBy()
.ThenByDescending()
.ThenByDescending()
```

I don't like the public parameterless constructor of `AgentCommission`. What use does it have ? IMHO none, so you could just delete it. Also having `public` setters can do some harm and should be avoided if the same values can be set by the constructor.

Adding a constructor which takes an `IEnumerable<AgentCommission>` to the `BetCommission` class would be a good idea.

Applying the mentioned points will lead to

```
public class BetCommission
{
    public int TotalCommission { get; private set; }
    public List<AgentCommission> AgentCommissions { get; }

    public BetCommission(IEnumerable<AgentCommission> agentCommissions)
    {
        AgentCommissions = new List<AgentCommission>(agentCommissions);
    }

    public BetCommission() : this(Enumerable.Empty<AgentCommission>())
    {}

    public void AddAgentCommission(AgentCommission agentCommission)
    {
        AgentCommissions.Add(agentCommission);
        TotalCommission += agentCommission.Commission;
    }
}

public void CalculateCommission()
{
    var levelCommissions = userCommissions.GroupBy(x => new { x.MarketType, x.Level }).ToList();
    var keysGrouping = userCommissions.GroupBy(x => new { x.SportId, x.LeagueId, x.MarketType }).ToList();

    foreach (var bpKey in keysGrouping)
    {
        var commissionsForCurrentKey = levelCommissions.Where(x => x.Key.MarketType == bpKey.Key.MarketType)
                                                     .SelectMany(x => x)
                                                     .Where(x => (x.SportId == bpKey.Key.SportId) && (x.LeagueId == bpKey.Key.LeagueId) && (x.Level > 0))
                                                     .OrderBy(x => x.Level)
                                                     .ThenByDescending(x => x.LeagueId)
                                                     .ThenByDescending(x => x.SportId);

        var agentCommissions = CreateAgentCommissions(commissionsForCurrentKey)
        var betCommission = new BetCommission(agentCommissions);

        var sportId = bpKey.Key.SportId ?? 0;
        var leagueId = bpKey.Key.LeagueId ?? 0;
        var key = $"{userId}-{sportId}-{leagueId}-{bpKey.Key.MarketType}";

        betCommissionsByUser.AddOrUpdate(key, betCommission, (k, v) => betCommission);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my code in according to your suggestions. My main concern is the performance ( and the ugliness ) with the multiple groupby and then unwrapping again.

Comment: Nitpicking, but you can call `agentCommision.ToList()` in the constructor. Another thing, in short methods like `AddAgentCommission` I would shorten the parameter name to `commission`. There are so many other things in there explaining what this is.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing some querying concepts here. The bet seems to be about a sport and a league:

```
var bet = new UserBet(sport, league, amount); // and probably more...
```

Then there are agents handling that bet:

```
var allCommissions = Query.GetAgentCommissionsForBet(bet);
```

To keep this query simple, I would return all commissions for all agents matching sport or leage, assuming league is unique for the sport. Agent 1 would have two entries in this list, Agent 2 would have three.

Next step is to get the best ones from this list:

```
var commissions = Calculator.CalculateSpecificCommissions(allCommissions, bet);
```

Then the calculator could group all commissions on agent and pick the most specific based on the bet.

I see two possible performance problems here:

1. The commission query. I have no idea if there are many agents, or how difficult it is to retrieve their commissions. This may, or may not, be a bottleneck. By moving the query out of the way, it would be easier to introduce more efficient database schemas or caching.
2. The commission calculator. In my head, I see a list being filtered in memory. That by itself should be fast, but I know nothing about how many times that calculation needs to be done or when it's done.

I suggest you profile your code for bottlenecks if you haven't already done so. I had to figure out once, why a certain piece of code needed 40 minutes to generate two short chapters of text: There were millions of synchronous calls to the database over the network. That's an order of magnitude more than there were words in said chapters.